# Chrome Extension. Official docs: "Popup can invoke functions on the background page"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html under **UI Pages**

> The popup doesn't need to duplicate code that's in the background page because the popup can invoke functions on the background page."

I have a function called functionBack() in the background page. This function is undefined if I call it from the pop up. What do they mean with that statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you can call it as:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().functionBack()
```

and it will be executed inside background page context.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!